# Export Parent Class Without Base Class in C++

Tags: c++, dllexport

Given the classes `Foo` and `Bar` where `Bar` is derived from `Foo`, how could I export `Bar` without having to export `Foo` ?

**Foo.h**

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo();
        virtual bool Read(...);
        virtual bool Write(...);
        ~Foo();
};
```

**Bar.h**

```
#ifdef BUILD_DLL
#    include "Foo.h"
#    define EXTERNAL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#    define EXTERNAL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif 

class EXTERNAL Bar: public Foo
{
    public:
        Bar();
        bool Read(...);
        bool Write(...);
        ~Bar();
};
```

**Edit**

This is the warning that Visual C++ 2010 gives me:

> warning C4275: non dll-interface class 'Foo' used as base for dll-interface class 'Bar'

**Edit #2**

Here's what I did to sort-of solve the issue. I made `Foo` and `Bar` separate DLL's. The client application links to Bar.dll and Bar.dll links to Foo.dll. This works well for what I was trying to achieve...

Comment: Using Visual C++ I do not get an error, but I do get a warning. I will have to wait until tomorrow to tell you what the warning is. The issue is going to come from importing the class since `Foo` won't be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't that work? It should. Just because you're not explicitly exporting the class doesn't mean the logic isn't in the binary. The symbols just aren't visible to anything importing that class.

Your solution should do it. Are you getting linking errors or what?

EDIT: I just saw you only include the header for `Foo` in one case. You don't need to do that:

```
#ifdef BUILD_DLL
#    define EXTERNAL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#    define EXTERNAL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif 

#include "Foo.h"

class EXTERNAL Bar: public Foo
{
    public:
        Bar();
        bool Read(...);
        bool Write(...);
        ~Bar();
};
```

This way you can't use `Foo` in a different module since it's not exported, but you can use and declare `Bar`.

Comment: I doubt that it can work this way: how is `class EXTERNAL Bar: public Foo` expected to work if `Foo` is not visible?

Comment: Luchian, you should be correct in the first place. A DLL exports functions not types so when you say class EXTERNAL Bar that is shorthand for saying that every method of Bar is exported. Just because the constructor of Bar calls the constructor Foo doesn't mean Foo's constructor needs to be exported otherwise you would need to export every function called by Bar(), Bar::Read(), Bar::Write() and ~Bar().

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I would think that this should compile, but if the definition of Foo is not available to a caller, how could they create an instance without knowing the size?  If Bar is an interface (if so, give it something pure virtual), then your code looks fine, because no one will instantiate it.

Comment: @BowieOwens - same question as to Luchian, I just couldn't seem to do two tags in a single comment...

Comment: @mike that is Foo's definition.

Answer (score 1):

Foo is needed to create a Bar instance - in fact, to create Bar, Foo's constructor is called prior to Bar's constructor.

I highly doubt you can export one and use it without exporting the other.

Comment: Why the downvote? If I'm wrong fine but let me know what wasn't right at least :p

Comment: W00te, you can export a derived class without exporting the base class. If an exported function calls another function, that other function doesn't need to be exported too.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what is this good for?

If you simply try to hide Foo from you customers (like i sometimes do, but not with Foo), just export it as usual...

Make a Dll out of it (link Foo.cpp to your Bar.dll) and kill the Foo class from the headers you deliver with you library/Dll file.

A inhertited class isn't visible to the user of an dll (when you don't choose to export the methods of this class with #define EXTERNAL __declspec(dllexport).

So: Foo is hidden to the user/customer.

Just relax ;)

Answer (score 0):

As w00te mentioned earlier you can't do this the way you suggest.

Could you please provide description of your use case? May be some other decisions would be helpful? F.ex. if you need to pass the Bar object outside of the dll you can create interface to it and reveal it instead of Bar object.